# Sequlize Update table with his associations

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, express, sequelize.js

I need to update the Movies and Actors tables. I pass movie data and actors array(array of actors names), I need to update the movie table by movie data and update actors table by actors array

```
  const { id } = req.movie;
  const { actors, ...updatedMovieData } = req.body;

  const movie = await Movie.update(req.body, {
    where: {
      id,
    },
  });

  res.status(200).json(movie);
```

`

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @Ralle  
 const { id } = req.movie;
      const { actors, ...updatedMovieData } = req.body;
      const movie = await Movie.update(req.body, {
        where: {
          id,
        },
      });
Movies and Actors have belongs to many assotiation
I need to update Movie and Actors table

Comment: I meant, post your code in the question. Put your code between backticks.

Comment: @Ralle check pls

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @MohammadHoseinBalkhani i need to update associate table Actors when update Movies. How i can do that?

Comment: @Matviy first you need to make a many to many relationship with table movies-actors and then [Belongs to many](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/associations/belongs-to-many.js~belongstomany) and if you set the update on cascade it would automatically update if you update one side

Answer (score 0):

You didnt post again much in your question.
But it seems to me that you are missing something.
You want to take the id from the movie and updating it.
You are doing that from req.movie.
Where does req.movie comes from? Do you add that in some middleware function?

Default there will not be any req.movie.
A good solution can be that your route sends the id as param. Like so:

http://localhost:3000/api/movie/123

Where 3000 is the port where your api server is running.
api/movie the name of your route.(should be put/patch in your backend).

123 ist the id of the movie.

Now from the request you can get the id like so:

```
    const {id} = req.params
```

Comment: i use middleware where i set req.movie. I find movie in middleware by req.params

Comment: Then i dont understand your problem. Describe it better and psot all the code related to the question please.